# C++ implementation of WAR card game using stack throws conversion error

Tags: c++, algorithm, compiler-errors, stack

I am trying to implement WAR card game in C++. I have the following data file from which I extract card's value and card suit.

```
7 hearts
Q spades
9 clubs
A hearts
10 spades
3 spades
K diamonds
10 hearts
6 spades
3 clubs
K hearts
9 spades
6 clubs
3 diamonds
A spades
J clubs
8 diamonds
5 hearts
A clubs
J diamonds
8 hearts
4 spades
A diamonds
J hearts
7 spades
4 clubs
7 clubs
4 diamonds
K spades
10 clubs
7 diamonds
4 hearts
K clubs
10 diamond
6 diamonds
3 hearts
Q clubs
9 diamonds
8 spades
5 clubs
2 diamonds
J spades
8 clubs
5 diamonds
2 hearts
6 hearts
2 spades
Q diamonds
9 hearts
5 spades
2 clubs
Q hearts
7 hearts
Q spades
9 clubs
A hearts
10 spades
3 spades
K diamonds
10 hearts
6 spades
3 clubs
K hearts
9 spades
6 clubs
3 diamonds
A spades
J clubs
8 diamonds
5 hearts
A clubs
J diamonds
8 hearts
4 spades
A diamonds
J hearts
7 spades
4 clubs
7 clubs
4 diamonds
K spades
10 clubs
7 diamonds
4 hearts
K clubs
10 diamond
6 diamonds
3 hearts
Q clubs
9 diamonds
8 spades
5 clubs
2 diamonds
J spades
8 clubs
5 diamonds
2 hearts
6 hearts
2 spades
Q diamonds
9 hearts
5 spades
2 clubs
Q hearts
```

Firstly, I do reshuffling of the cards once by splitting the data file to half and putting 2 halves of data in 2 different arrays then shuffling by merging the array. Then I used stacks to push those cards for 4 stacks (representing 4 players in my game.) The algorithm is pretty simple as I count the total denomination of each player in the game and count the total to declare the winner. I get the following error in my code: "No viable conversion from 'string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') to 'const carddata'". Please provide insights on what it means. Following is the code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//to represent value of each card and the suit of each card
struct carddata{
    string denomination;
    string suits;

};
//creating template and prototype for using stack
template <typename T, typename vectorData = std::vector<T> >

class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(int);
    bool isFull() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void push(T const&);
    T pop();
    int Size();
    void makeEmpty();
    T peek();
private:
    int top;
    int size;
    vectorData data;
};

class StackException: public std::logic_error {
public:
    StackException(const std::string& message = "")
    :logic_error(message.c_str()){
    }

};

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
Stack<T, vectorData>::Stack(int s){
    data.resize(size);
    size = s;
    top = -1;
}

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
bool Stack<T, vectorData>::isEmpty() const {
    return (top == -1);
}

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
int Stack<T, vectorData>::Size() {
    return size;
}

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
bool Stack<T, vectorData>::isFull() const {
    return (top == size -1);
}

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
void Stack<T, vectorData>::push(T const& newItem){
    if (isFull()){
        throw StackException("Full Size limit exceeded");
    }
    else {
        top += 1;
        if (data.size() == 0){
            data.resize(size);
        }
        data[top] = newItem;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
T Stack<T, vectorData>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw StackException("Stack Empty");
    } else {
        top--;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
void Stack<T, vectorData>::makeEmpty() {
    if (!isEmpty()){
        data.resize(0);
        size = 0;
        top = -1;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename vectorData>
T Stack<T, vectorData>::peek(){
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw StackException("Stack Empty");
    }
    return data[top];
}

int main(){
    carddata game;//declaring the struct
    ifstream myfile;//create file object
    myfile.open("infile.txt");//opening the file
    carddata firsthalf[26];//declare array to store 1st half of the carddata present in the infile
    carddata secondhalf[26];//declare array to store 2nd half of the carddata present in the infile
    carddata entirecard[52];//declare array to merge and shuffle the card

    for (int i = 0; i< 26; i++){
        myfile >> game.denomination >> game.suits;
        firsthalf[i] = game;
            }

    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++){
        myfile >> game.denomination >> game.suits;
        secondhalf[j] = game;
    }
    //this function is used to merge and create a new set of cards containing 52 cards (to shuffle).
    int i =0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i<26 && j<52){
        entirecard[j] = firsthalf[i];
        j ++;
        entirecard[j] = secondhalf[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    //we need to put data onto the stack. These stacks represent 4 people in my game
    Stack<carddata> stack1(13);
    Stack<carddata> stack2(13);
    Stack<carddata> stack3(13);
    Stack<carddata> stack4(13);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    // i am trying to push card's denomination, but get a problem
    while (a < 13 && b < 13 && c < 13 && d < 13){
        stack1.push(entirecard[a].denomination);
        stack1.push(entirecard[b].denomination);
        stack1.push(entirecard[c].denomination);
        stack1.push(entirecard[d].denomination);
        a++;b++;c++;d++;
    }
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;
    int player3 = 0;
    int player4 = 0;
    //to add values of each card for each player
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        if(stack1.pop()=="J"){
            player1 += 10;
        }
        else if (stack2.pop()=="J"){
            player2 += 10;
        }
        else if (stack3.pop()=="J"){
            player3 += 10;
        }
        else if(stack1.pop()=="Q"){
            player1 += 11;
        }
        else if (stack2.pop()=="Q"){
            player2 += 11;
        }
        else if (stack3.pop()=="Q"){
            player3 += 11;
        }
        else if(stack1.pop()=="K"){
            player1 += 12;
        }
        else if (stack2.pop()=="K"){
            player2 += 12;
        }
        else if (stack3.pop()=="K"){
            player3 += 12;
        }
        else if (stack1.pop()=="A"){
            player1 += 13;
        }
        else if (stack2.pop()=="A"){
            player2 += 13;
        }
        else if (stack3.pop()=="A"){
            player3 += 13;
        }

        else{
            player1 += stack1.pop();
            player2 += stack2.pop();
            player3 += stack3.pop();
            player4 += stack4.pop();
        }

    }

    if (player1>player2&&player1>player3 && player1 >> player4){
        cout << "Player1 wins";
    }

    else if (player2>player1&&player2>player3 && player2>> player4){
        cout << "Player2 wins";
    }
    else if (player3>player1&&player3>player2 && player3>> player4){
        cout << "Player3 wins";
    }
    else if (player4>player1&&player4>player2 && player4 >> player3){
        cout << "Player4 wins";
    }
    else if (player1==player2==player3==player4){
        cout << "Player1 wins";
    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please clarify which line cause this error.

Comment: What isn't clear about the error?  You are trying to store `std::string` in a vector that takes `carddata`.